# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver after deploying to jar

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc

This question has asked many times, but this one is slightly different. In my case, I'm not getting any error when running from Eclipse, it successfully runs and is able to connect to MySQL.

I have a Maven project in Eclipse, using the MySQL database and MySQL Connector/J for connection.

However, after deploying to jar I am getting the error.

I am using `mvn clean install` to deploy

I have added dependency in pom.xml like:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.49</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am using following command to run the jar file
 `java -jar ./target/project.jar`

but this gives

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

What's wrong here?

Comment: Please show the pom.xml of your project. It sounds like you haven't configured Maven to generate the appropriate `Class-Path` entry in the manifest, and put the dependencies in the right location.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the scope from `runtime` to `compile` or delete String scope at all.
This String talks about that this dependency don't load in compile time.
When you call `maven install` then happens source compile and this dependency don't add to classpath.

Comment: I tried that, still getting the same error

Comment: try to use mvn clean -am install

Comment: getting build failed while running `mvn clean -am instal`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<scope>runtime</scope>` from the mysql maven dependency as it makes the jar available only in the runtime. Either you don't put the scope at all or put that in `compile` time.

Do `mvn clean install`. It will work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.49</version>    
</dependency>
```

Also, you need to create an executable fat jar using maven. Normal jar created by maven is non-executable. It won't work.

To create a executable jar by maven. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven).

Comment: tried this as well, but getting same error.

Comment: @NITESHKUMAR Share your codebase through github to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @NITESHKUMAR I got the issue. No, it will not work. You have to create an executable fat jar using maven to make things work.

Comment: @NITESHKUMAR Did you get my point ?

Comment: no, I didn't, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @NITESHKUMAR You need to jar which executes from a main method.

Comment: @NITESHKUMAR Maven doesn't create a jar which is executable.

Comment: @NITESHKUMAR You need to tell maven to create an executable jar.

Comment: @NITESHKUMAR Now, it's clear. ?

Comment: I am trying, will let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228666/discussion-between-nitesh-kumar-and-anish-b).

Comment: @NITESHKUMAR Wait. Follow this link to create an executable jar using maven - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: I already have that, you are talking about the entry point inside mainfest tag, is it?

Comment: @NITESHKUMAR Sorry ! Yes

Comment: I didn't do that, really

Comment: You help a lot, I tried up voting, but not able to so, any way just wanted to say thanks for your efforts

Comment: But issue is not solved yet

Comment: @NITESHKUMAR Ok :). Not problem.